# Having issue with installing iSGL3D engine

Tags: ios, isgl3d

I am trying to install `iSGL3D` template for xcode 5.x , I open Terminal then drag `installTemplatesXcode4.sh` on it and press enter, but nothing happens !

[image]

appreciate for any help !

Comment: Just as an advice, you can also copy & paste the output of your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rsync is failing to copy some files:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Momeks/templates/xcode4/iSGL3D Base.xctemplate" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Does the directory `/Users/Momeks/templates/xcode4/` exist?